# how to access object properties inside another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Customer {
  name: 'jen',
  options:
   [ Order {
       _price: 11,
       _option: 'vegan',
       _name: 'V for Vegan',
       _ingredients:
        [ Ingredient { name: 'mint', price: 0.5 },
          Ingredient { name: 'peanuts', price: 0.5 } ] },
     Order {
       _price: 11,
       _option: 'vegetarian',
       _name: 'Veggie',
       _ingredients: [] } ] }
```

I'm having a hard time logging out this part:

```
_ingredients:
            [ Ingredient { name: 'mint', price: 0.5 },
              Ingredient { name: 'peanuts', price: 0.5 } ] },
```

I can get to log out this:

```
Options: vegan
[object Object],[object Object]

Options: vegetarian
```

But I would like it to be something like

```
Options: vegan
mint, peanuts
```

My last attempt was looping through _ingredients but it is returning undefined. My code so far:

```
getBill() {
      let totalPrice = 0;

      console.log(`
        Your current bill:
        `)

      this.options.forEach((i) => {
        console.log(`
          Option: ${i._option}
          Extra Ingredients: ${i._ingredients.forEach((j) => {j.name})}
        `)
        totalPrice += i._price;
      })

      console.log(`
        Total Price: ${totalPrice} $
        `)
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing really magical about plain old JavaScript objects, the property is accessible if it's visible.

Comment: hi @tadman but I cannot log out the property? it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. You can try with `array#map`

Comment: @catch22 can you post the raw json object? I'm having a hard time seeing the problem. What is `this.options`?

Comment: @HassanImam is right, when you're doing this `${i._ingredients.forEach((j) => {j.name})}` you're logging what `forEach` returns, not what's being done inside of it. And it always returns `undefined`.

Comment: If you are using ES6 Syntax, you can use a class and extend it. Or you can loop over a `new` instance.

Comment: @PHPglue can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a JavaScript function error as [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't actually return anything useful. If you read the documentation you'll see the return value is explicitly specified as `undefined`, which is what you're probably getting. You'll need to do something with that, like join them together.

```
Extra Ingredients: ${i._ingredients.map(_i => _i.name).join(', ')}
```

Using [Lodash](http://lodash.com) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) will give you a `map` function that takes a string as well:

```
Extra Ingredients: ${_.map(i._ingredients, 'name').join(', ')}
```

That actually returns the values you want, it plucks out the `name` property, which you can then give a cosmetic treatment with the `join` to combine it into a well-formed string list.

Comment: Why not native javascript map?

Comment: Your snippet with underscore returns `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`.
And with map it's not returning any error or undefined, but returns only the `Extra Ingredients: , ` and not the name.

Comment: @catch22 I've added a native JavaScript example. `_` represents one of Lodash or Underscore, so you must load those for it to work.

Comment: Ok, adding `const _ = require('lodash')` and using your Lodash option has made it work! I've never heard of this, so I will look into it. Thank you so much! 
Just for future references, the `.map` one didn't work, it was only outputting the `,` of `.join(', ')`

Comment: They should both work. The advantage of Lodash is not this particular function, but the wealth of other toys and tools it provides. Hassan pointed out a small error in the code there which may have fixed your issue. The native `map` version is probably a good default, but the Lodash version allows for more flexibility. It's largely a matter of preference.

Comment: @catch22 regular non-lodash `map` should also work. What exactly did you try? I think providing `lodash` example overcomplicates this answer, you can pass string using `_i["name"]` syntax with regular `map`.

Comment: @Walk All good points. I went with the Lodash version first because I suffered for years under the tyranny of Internet Explorer and I'm not used to having nice things like ES6.

Comment: the new correction of the snippet in `.map` is working. I'll go for that as it's the simplest, but hearing of Lodash is a treasure too. Thanks a lot!